# Load file as byte array with no allocate it in memory C#

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I'm working on an endpoint to uploading a file and sending it to WCF Service.

I have an endpoint that accept a one file in form-data. A user can upload up to 50 files, but files are uploaded one by one (one at the time). Each file can be up to 5MB. So, in the code I read the file as Stream, and I must send a file to WCF Service as byte array.
That’s the problem. I don’t want to allocate 5MB array in the memory just to send it to WCF Service. 50 files * 5MB = 250MB. It’s a lot.

Not-optimised code looks like this below.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    MultipartMemoryStreamProvider multipartMemoryStreamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    HttpContent file = multipartMemoryStreamProvider.Contents.GetFormValue("file");
    int length = (int) file.Headers.ContentLength;
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[length]; // allocating up to 5MB :(

    using (Stream stream = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        await stream.ReadAsync(fileContent, 0, length);
    }

    await _documentService.UploadAsync("filename", fileContent);
}
```

I tried to use ArrayPool, and it worked great, but ArrayPool gives me an array that has minimum of asked bytes. So, I was sending more bytes that I wanted (e.g. for 420KB files I received 512KB array). I can use ArrayPool.Create(). However, I don’t want to end up with huge number of pools.

Also, I checked Array.Resize (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.8) but it copies elements from old array to new array (allocated again the same array).

Span is not useful because .ToArray() method will allocate a new byte array.

Do you have any idea how to create byte array without allocating?

Comment: If you are using WCF, first thing you need to configure your endpoint binding to use streams else it will be already buffered in memory. And you should change your contract to use `Stream` not `byte[]`

Comment: I'm not responsible for this service, so let say it's not possible to change it as Stream :) I know, it would be the best and easiest solution.

Comment: if 5 MB is a problem you should probably upgrade your hardware. You can save the Files to disk, and then only read chunks of 1024kb at a time and send those. Your ReadAsync func also allows to set an offset and a length so you could read chunks and send those.

Comment: If the service forces you to use `byte[]` you have no chance to avoid it. Just read all the bytes via `File.ReadAllBytes`

Comment: @Charles 5MB per file, 50 files per user. It's 250MB. Let's assume you have 100 users that send files in the same time. It will be ~2.5GB allocated bytes in LOH. If the GC collects LOH, it collects all generations. It's not cheap operation. My LOH will be fragmented, a lot objects might be promoted from Gen0 to Gen1, from Gen1 to Gen2, just because I'm allocating arrays in foolish way.

Comment: @Eldar that's what I thought. Nevertheless, I hope it's possible and somebody might know the answer :) I also thought about reflection, or unsafe code.

Comment: @Pyotreq process one file at a time, even when they all send at the same time you only have 5mb * 100 users = 500mb. But as i said before you're not forced to read the full file in one part. For sending: write chunked to the RequestStream. Stream.Write(buffer, 0, 1024);

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "create byte array without allocating".  As long as API requires array you must create new one as size is part of the instance (the only optimization you can do is to reuse arrays of the same size).

So your options are:

- live with it. If memory allocation is a problem you can force garbage collection.
- change the API to be either streaming or support partial uploads or use regular POST instead of WCF methods.